# CDK step function to get the status from lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I'm following this  [example suit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-stepfunctions-readme.html#example) to able to create a step function and execute lambdas.
However, I'm very much interested in catching the status of the lambda's response.

As per the document,  `// Lambda's result in a field called "status" in the response`
what does it mean `result in a field called status`? can anyone shed any light on how to put a result in a field as a status? I'm doing it in python.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of catching response of lambda function from step function.

1. Using `add_retry` and `add_catch` to handle any exception from lambda function
   eg.

```
            .start(record_ip_task
                   .add_retry(errors=["States.TaskFailed"],
                              interval=core.Duration.seconds(2),
                              max_attempts=2)
                   .add_catch(errors=["States.ALL"], handler=notify_failure_job)) \
```

2. Response value from lambda function such as `return '{"Result": True}` then the step function job will check that value for next task, eg.

```
                            .next(
                                is_block_succeed
                                    .when(step_fn.Condition.boolean_equals('$.Result', False), notify_failure_job)
                                    .otherwise(send_slack_task)
                            )
```

Ref: https://dev.to/vumdao/aws-guardduty-combine-with-security-hub-and-slack-17eh

Comment: the link is working but some important contents links are not working like `Step function and state machine for catching IPv4` can you share me updated one or GitHub to refer.

Comment: thanks, @vumado appreciated. I have created another request will it possible for you to have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67166351/stepfunction-to-pass-the-output-of-lambdas-to-another-lamabda