# Stepfunction to pass the output of lambdas to another lamabda

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a step function state machine that has 3 lambdas e.g.
`lambda_a`,
`Lambda_b`
and `lambda_c`

`lambda_c` expects input from both `lambda_a` and `lambda_b`
`lambda_a` and `lambda_b` both return payload as a return and `lambda_c` expects these payloads as input.
and they called/linked like this:
lambda_a

```
lambda_a_step = sfn_tasks.LambdaInvoke(self, 'lambda_a',
                                                          lambda_function=lambda_a_function,
                                                          payload_response_only=True,
                                                          result_path='$.lambda_a.Payload')
```

Lambda_b

```
lambda_a_step = sfn_tasks.LambdaInvoke(self, 'lambda_b',
                                                              lambda_function=lambda_b_function,
                                                              payload_response_only=True,
                                                              result_path='$.lambda_b.Payload')
```

Both sample output payload looks like this from lambda:

```
{
  "Comment": "Insert your JSON here",
  "lambda_a": {
    "Payload": {
      "result": "succeeded",
      "start_date": "20210419 11:50:55",
      "finish_date": "20210419 11:51:00",
      "reason": "No errors found in the log file"
    }
```

How can I pass the complete payload from lambda_a and lambda_b to my `lambda_c`?  i.e. lambda_c should get the input from lambda_a.payload and lambda_b.Payload

In the execution output, I could see both payloads. But how to pass these 2 payloads to my lambda_c?

Comment: How the the lambda's running now? A then B? A and B in parallel?

Comment: A and then B....as a next chain